# Getting the examples in libspotify to work under Windows 7

Tags: c, api, spotify, libspotify

I want to get started with libspotify on my Win 7 machine but I dont have a clue on how to get it all setup so that I can even run the examples included in the pack. I have a Spotify Premium account and I have tried installing libspotify by copying libspotify.dll to c:\windows, c:\windows\system32  and to c:\windows\SysWOW64 and also changed the path variable to include the path where libspotify.dll is located but I still dont understand how to get the examples to work.

I have Code::Blocks installed but as soon as I try to import and run any of the .c files included in the /examples/ folder I get all kinds of error messages. The truth is that I am not even sure how to install libspotify and the documentation is absolutely non existent so for a beginner it is impossible to even have a chance at getting started.
Is there somebody out there who can do a simple walkthrough on how to install libspotify and get the examples up and running on a Win 7 (64-bit) machine?

The only thing I really want to do with libspotify is to be able to via a command prompt or something like that be able to queue a song in Spotify so I dont really care about the other parts. But I can probably solve that by myself as long as I can get an example up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly libspotify is not well-supported on Windows, in fact the example code won't even build because there is no Windows audio driver for them. Your best bet to just get up and running would be to use mingw, or linux in a VirtualBox environment.