# How to render Spotify PCM stream on Windows

Tags: c++, spotify, audio-streaming, pcm, libspotify

Currently I am trying to use the libspotify lib to write a Windows Spotify Player. I'm new to audio streaming but not to video streaming.

I have the basics working for most of the user data and track info but the problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to render the Raw PCM data on Windows.

I've been looking at the Jukebox example but it doesn't compile on Windows and I would like to keep this app as a native Windows app.  This example is using OpenAL to render the stream and just wondering if that the best solution (vs something like Windows Audio Session API).

Seems like playing back a track should be straightforward. Am I missing something? It's turning out to be quite difficult.

I did see this post which is a little discouraging. 
[Getting the examples in libspotify to work under Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908077/getting-the-examples-in-libspotify-to-work-under-windows-7)

Any help or direction on this topic would be very much appreciated!  Working samples even better. :)

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you're asking how to play PCM sound data on Windows, and all the spotify stuff is irrelevant?

Comment: @Tommyg There are a lot of APIs for playing audio.  WASAPI is the most common way if you don't need portability.  OpenAL is helpful if you need its 3D positioning or portability to other platforms.

Comment: Update: Finally had a chance to get back to this project.  I ended up going with OpenAL and got it working.  I basically ported the jukebox sample app to Windows just to learn the api better.